# Getting high size image in didFinishPicking method

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift5

I am fetching the image from photo library. But the size of the image is different than actual size.

Image size in Photos App :- 1.8 MB
Image size in mail attachment:- 2.7 MB (when using actual size)
Image size that i am getting in didFinish Method :- 5.9 MB

Your help is greatly appreciated

I am using this code to get the image:-

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

```
var uploadImage:UIImage?
if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage
{
    uploadImage = image
}
else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage{
    uploadImage = image
}
debugPrint("Image actual size :\(uploadImage!.getFileSizeInfo())")
```

}

Comment: Have you HEIC and/or Live Photo in Camera app ?

Comment: yes i have live photos, but if i use downloaded media(.jpeg) of 75KB its size is also showing 295KB .